# On a formula for the Auslander-Reiten translate

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

For an Artin algebra $A$ and an indecomposable non-projective module $M$ we should have that $\tau(M) \cong \nu \Omega^2(M)$ iff $Ext_A^i(M,A)=0$ for $i=1,2$. ($\nu$ being the Nakayama functor)

Applying this to the indecomposable module $A$ as an $A^e$-module ($A^e$ being the enveloping algebra of A) and noting that $Ext_{A^e}^i(A,A^e)=Ext_A^i(D(A),A)$, we get that in case $Ext_A^i(D(A),A)=0$ for $i=1,2$, we have that $\tau(A) \cong \nu \Omega^2(A)$ as $A^e$-modules.

Now tensoring this with an arbitrary $A$-module $M$, we get $\tau(A) \otimes_A M \cong \nu \Omega^2(A) \otimes_A M$.

Now we should have that up to projective summands $P$ that $\tau(A) \otimes_A M = \tau(M) \oplus P$ as $A$-modules.

Now I wonder whether we can also write $\nu \Omega^2(A) \otimes_A M$ in a nice form (avoiding the tensor product) to get a non-trivial global formula for $\tau(M)$?

I know that $\Omega^2(A) \otimes_A M \cong \Omega^2(M) \oplus P'$ for some projective module $P'$, but the Nakayama functor coming from the enveloping algebra seems to be more complicated.
It can not be true that $\tau(M) \cong \nu \Omega^2(M)$ in general except for $A$ being selfinjective, since for example $A$ could have finite global dimension and then the formula is wrong for $M$ having projective dimension equal to one in general.